# in flutter when I add value database to map value null is add why

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, mapping, stream-builder

SQLite database in flutter

'''
{

```
Future<List<Dataid>> getPerson() async {
       var dbC = await db;
       List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps =await dbC.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $TABLE");
       List<Dataid> persons = [];
       if (maps.length > 0) {
         for (int i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {       
             persons.add(Dataid.fromMap(maps[i]));      ///error is in this line 
              print(maps.length);
              print("${maps[i]}");
              print(persons);
             }  }
         return persons;  }
```

'''
when I get data from database and add into map it add null value ??
here
'''
{

```
   class Dataid {
   String id;
   String name;
   String srname;
   Dataid(this.id, this.name, this.srname);

   Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'srname': srname,
   };
   return map;
}

 Dataid.fromMap(
   Map<String, dynamic> map,
  ) {
    id = map['id'];
    name = map['name'];
    srname = map['srname'];
 }

 }
```

'''
my error is:
'''
{

```
  print(maps.length);
              print("${maps[i]}");
              print(persons);
   //when i print this result is
    means problem
    I/flutter (31391): 30
    I/flutter (31391): {ID: 1, NAME: david, SRNAME: john}
    I/flutter (31391): [Dataid{id: null, name: null, age: null}]
```

'''
problem during add into map a

Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure as I haven't used `SQLite` with `Flutter` yet, but maybe the problem is that the keys in `maps[i]` are uppercase and you are using their lowercase forms in `Dataid.fromMap()`.

Try this:

```
 Dataid.fromMap(
   Map<String, dynamic> map,
  ) {
    id = map['ID'];
    name = map['NAME'];
    srname = map['SRNAME'];
 }
```

Comment: where i add this ,  it is already add in my Dataid class

Comment: Replace your `Dataid.fromMap` with the code I gave you.

Comment: Thankyou , yaa my mistake is due to small letter in map['ID']  

Comment: No problem! :) Please consider clicking on the green checkmark to mark the answer as correct.